# How can I get password(key) using encrypt string and plain text in jasypt?

Tags: jasypt

I used jasypt-1.9.2 to encrypt property value in configuration file.

Unfortunately, I lost key but I have encrypted string and plain text.

In this situation, Is there way to get key from encrypted string and plain text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the encryption was not a trivial method the answer is NO.

The best chance you have is to try potential passwords and find one that works.

Note: critical passwords need to be saved securely somewhere that is very hard to loose by accident. One solution is on paper, in a good safe, not a cheap fireproof only safe. Perhaps in a bank Safety Deposit Box.

Comment: Thank you for replying the answer.